# VSC Terminal- How to delete the path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to learn Python, and while trying to use the terminal, I cannot make the path disappear.

So far, I've been able to make disappear some things but not the path...

Original Look:

[Terminal Default Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6txb.png)

Now:

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4q1F.png)

This is some of the code I've used:

`"My PowerShell": { "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe", "args": ["-NoLogo"]`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It suggests just ignoring the folder path in the terminal, but if you insist
you can:

Change `console` to `"console": "internalConsole"` in the launch.json file and take `F5` to debug the python script instead of `Run Python File in Terminal`.

Or you can try to install the `Code Runner` extension and then take `Run Code` to execute the python script.